# SSIS Deploying Master - Child packages in MSDB

Tags: ssis, bids

I have a master SSIS package with three child packages and all these packages are part of a single solution. I 'm calling child packages through Execute Package task and connection managers pointing to child packages on the file system.

Now i want to deploy these packages in MSDB database. I have created SSISDeploymentManifest file through deployment utility. I'm planning to select SQLServer as the option while running manifest file, but how do i change connection managers to point to child packages on msdb database instead of the ones on file system.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To do this:

1. Change the click on your Execute package task.
2. Go to the section which says package and change the location property from File System to SQL Server.  You will need to define a new connection to your database associated with your integration services server.
3. Locate the packages you deployed to msdb and you will have the location.

You can then delete the associated package connections in your package, which will be no longer used as you are using msdb.